# The act of making rolls of dough

Tags: word-request, verbs, food

Bakers (usually) take small pieces of dough off much bigger dough that they already prepared before starting shaping it in a way they want like spreading or scoring it. I found a [picture](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%B7%D8%B1+%D8%AF%D8%B1+%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%84+%DA%86%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87+%DA%AF%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%86&client=ms-android-om-lge&biw=320&bih=452&prmd=visn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG67ydsYDSAhUHtBQKHdJfCc0Q_AUICSgC#tbm=isch&q=%DA%86%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87+%DA%AF%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%86+%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86&imgrc=lW3gNjxJZUYtVM:) that might help. In Persian, we call it *چانه گرفتن*. What's it called in english?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the dough has already risen (and is past the [final proof](http://breadbaking.about.com/od/breadbakersglossary/g/proofing.htm)):

I would call this the ***[divide](http://www.bakerpedia.com/processes/dough-dividing/)*** and pre-shape step.

It is the step before final shaping.  In this step you divide the dough into smaller balls. [image] (image from bakerpedia.com)

Answer (score 1):

[Shaping.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shaping)

```
tr.v. shaped, shap·ing, shapes
    1. To create or fashion, as:
        a. To give a particular form to (a material): shape the dough into baguettes.
```